# Can every python code be written in one line?

Tags: python

Can I write every complex python program in a single line?
Intuitively using semicolons wont suffice, as python depends on indention.

For example:

```py
print('hi')
m = '.'

while len(m) < 5:
    print('here')
    m = 'bye' + m

d = 2238
print(m, d)
```

Can I write this snippet in one line?

Answer (score 2):

Python has limited support for semi-colons to combine multiple statements on one line.

```
x = 10; if x == 10: print "x is 10"
```

However, compound statements that rely on indentation (like `if` and `while`) are limited to one-line bodies in their one-line form, and cannot themselves be followed by a semicolon. However, this part of the language is seldom, if ever, used in readable code and exists (IMO) primarily for interactive use on the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Every Python program can be written in one line by wrapping it in a `exec` statement and turning the original code into a string literal using `\n` instead of newlines. For your example, that is `exec("print('hi')\nm = '.'\nwhile len(m) < 5:\n    print('here')\n    m = 'bye' + m\n\nd = 2238\nprint(m, d)")`